# I got one of the Action Controller exception caught

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im making a rails application with a scaffold named `Styles`, a User made with devise and a model called `Category` to filter the `styles`. Im getting this execption caught in the `_form`page, this is the code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @style, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

  <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select a category"%>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Your style name" %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-custom2' %>

<% end %>
```

I have the simple_form and bootstrap gem installed, but i don´t think that´s the problem. The rails error page is hightlighting the `<% end %>` part, like that´s the problem but i don´t see why. The exact error is

```
SyntaxError in StylesController#new
C:/Users/mmrma/Downloads/Desktop/marina2.0/marinas-web/app/views/styles/_form.html.erb:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' '.freeze; end ; ^ C:/Users/mmrma/Downloads/Desktop/marina2.0/marinas-web/app/views/styles/_form.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' C:/Users/mmrma/Downloads/Desktop/marina2.0/marinas-web/app/views/styles/_form.html.erb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

Comment: What is the specific error? Also you misspelled `prompt` in your `select_tag`.

Comment: As outlined by @jdgray, it could be an error with your select tag option, though typically this is a hash option and would not break anything.

Also, you should include the exact error and message in your SO questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing parens tag on your `select_tag`

```
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select a category") %>
```

Comment: Oh! You beat me to it by 24 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the parentheses in your select tag. eg:

```
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select a category"%>
```

...should be...

```
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select a category") %>
```